# Can we have launch trajectories in GMAT?

Tags: trajectory, gmat, launch-trajectories

Is it possible to model launch trajectories from ground to a certain earth orbit in GMAT?

Comment: I don't think GMAT has a good troposphere model, which is pretty much essential for modeling launch. It does appear to have an exponential atmosphere model (not good at all) and MSIS-E-90 (outdated). I would choose the latter, but beware, it is outdated. It does not appear to model winds, which is something a good launch vehicle sim should do. Also, you'll need to make the launch vehicle's coefficient of drag change from a very low number to something like 2.2 once it gets on orbit.

Comment: So if I can do it (even if not perfect), how would I go about doing it?